# ¿Como puedo comparar los registros entre 2 bases de datos para comparar que sean idénticas? SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Tengo dos Base de Datos en Modo Full, sacadas de la misma copia, pero en una depure el Log a dejarlo a 1 MB y en la otra lo deje intacto, como puedo revisar que no haya habido perdida de información en la que se depuro el Log?

Answer (score 0):

Una de las mejores herramientas para realizar comparación entre Bases de datos y que vengo utilizando hace tiempo son las herramientas de Red Gate tanto **SQL Data compare** y **SQL compare** una para hacer comparaciones de datos y la otra para realizar comparaciones de estructura, lo único malo es que es una herramienta paga pero puedes bajarte la version full y utilizarla por 30 dias sin restricciones, te dejo el link de las herramientas.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/